# Sending HttpRequest to 2 different applications and comparing their results and performance

Tags: rest, http, architecture

I have a **module in an application 'A'** that serves a HttpRequest and computes a redirect url. I have developed **another application 'B'** that was written in another language that would do the same thing as that module in A plus some more amount of computation and redirect the client to another webpage.

I require ideas on the following

Q. How do I check if B redirects to the correct Url as the module in A? ( do note that the module in A would compute some url but A might do some more additional computation and redirect to another url. I am only interested in comparing the output from the module vs B)

Q. How do I performance test B against A (load, response time, etc)?

Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this in 2 ways,  server side and client side.

For server side you can use Date object in java or any other defined way in the language you are using to get the start time for http request received and the end time after redirect url call. 
Print these 2 times in log for both the cases.

For client side you can also write simple code on local machine  for rest calls and log the times as I mentions for server side

Please find the demo code below:

```
 Date start1 = new Date() ;
 // first http call
 //process data
 // redirect call http call
  Date end1 = new Date() 
 // print time for start1 and end1


  Date start2= new Date() ;
 // first http call
 //process data
 // redirect call http call
 Date end2= new Date() 

 // print time for start2 and end2
```

Comment: The assumption that time when http request processing starts is same for both applications is wrong.

Comment: I am sorry I think I havent mentioned it clearly.  I have added the dummy code hoping it will help